# Ubuntu not Detecting Bluetooth

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, bluez

I am using Ubuntu 23.10 version and before that I used latest LTS version. Ubuntu is not detecting my bluetooth hardware, I tried to reinstall blueZ and it is running perfectly but my laptop's bluetooth adapter is not detected. I used an external bluetooth dongle and it works fine. Currently I am using Acer TravelMate P440, Is the hardware incompatible or there are some missing drivers or packages?

$ lspci -nnk|grep -iA3 net; lsusb;

```
02:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 14)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1025:0947]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 48)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [Stone Peak 2 AC] [8086:5010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. Integrated Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 015: ID 1c7a:0603 LighTuning Technology Inc. ES603 Swipe Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b520 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HD WebCam
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

$ sudo dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'

```
[    0.102929] DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR [0x000000009d800000-0x000000009fffffff], contact BIOS vendor for fixes
[    0.102937] DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: Your BIOS is broken; bad RMRR [0x000000009d800000-0x000000009fffffff]
[    0.104163] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.142790] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.286662] systemd[1]: systemd-pcrmachine.service - TPM2 PCR Machine ID Measurement was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathExists=/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/StubPcrKernelImage-4a67b082-0a4c-41cf-b6c7-440b29bb8c4f).
[    3.213996] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.3216344376.0 7265-17.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.249082] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.249117] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    3.249121] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.249126] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.249129] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.249137] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.656319] audit: type=1400 audit(1705486854.821:98): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.firmware-updater" pid=692 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   26.098035] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   26.098042] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   26.098047] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 9045.185310] audit: type=1107 audit(1705498707.211:276): pid=744 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=20038 label="snap.postman.postman" peer_pid=2750 peer_label="unconfined"
[10655.857080] audit: type=1400 audit(1705507203.657:325): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firmware-updater.firmware-notifier" name="/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count" pid=26422 comm="firmware-notifi" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[19976.578687] audit: type=1400 audit(1705518008.588:408): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firmware-updater.firmware-notifier" name="/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count" pid=45548 comm="firmware-notifi" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[20618.544710] audit: type=1400 audit(1705547681.787:410): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firmware-updater.firmware-notifier" name="/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count" pid=47393 comm="firmware-notifi" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[21681.253746] audit: type=1400 audit(1705550408.608:465): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firmware-updater.firmware-notifier" name="/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count" pid=52532 comm="firmware-notifi" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[28372.555315] audit: type=1400 audit(1705561208.575:503): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firmware-updater.firmware-notifier" name="/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count" pid=56594 comm="firmware-notifi" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[37870.930775] audit: type=1400 audit(1705572008.369:567): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firmware-updater.firmware-notifier" name="/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count" pid=87902 comm="firmware-notifi" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk|grep -iA3 net; lsusb; sudo dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: Edited the questions with results of these commands.

Comment: Has Bluetooth worked in the past?

Comment: No, It's been like 3-4 months, I installed Ubuntu before that I was using Windows and It worked fine there. It just didn't worked on Linux but works on Windows

Comment: It might just need to BIOS reset to defaults as it isn't detecting the Bluetooth at all.  The Bluetooth on those Intel wifi cards always showed up in lsusb results